# PHP: MySQL variables value not getting changed in array?

Tags: php, mysql

I am having issues changing the values, of variables i have fetched from my MySQL database. I am trying this

```
foreach( $itemsCurrentSorted as $item ) {
    echo "pre: " . $item[4];
    $item[4] = 100;
    echo "after: " . $item[4];
}
```

the itemsCurrentSorted contains results from fetching rows from a MySQL database. The weird thing is, that the echo statements gives me the proper result. It seems to change the value. HOWEVER, the second it starts on a new iteration, it is like the value was never reset anyways. So it doesn't keep the new value?

So i guess my question in short is: How do you change the value, in a row you fetched from a MySQL database. Thanks on advance

Comment: try `foreach( $itemsCurrentSorted as &$item )`  but at the end after foreach use `unset($item)` to be safer side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try editing by reference

```
foreach ($key as &$value) {

}
```

The ampersand means it will make changes to the original array.

Comment: Besides the unintuitive naming of the operands I don't get why someone down voted this. This is a valid answer. +1 from me.

Comment: Ah thanks, that was exactly the issue. I had no idea you had to use the & in front of the fetched element if you wished to change it in the array. Thanks a bunch mate!